# How to check time range in PHP

Tags: php

I want to display an error if someone enter :

1. The same timeout/timein time
2. Overlap timeout/timein time
3. Is in range beetwen timeout/timein time

But it didn't work . the time still can be insert into database. Code as below :

```
<?php
    $connect      = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "db");
    global $connect;   

    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {   
        $timeout        = '08:30:00';
        $timein         = '12:30:00';
        $time_out_user  = $_POST['timeout'];
        $time_in_user   = $_POST['timein'];

        if(($time_out_user >= $timeout) && ($time_out_user <= $timein))
        {
            echo "Duplicate time";
        }
        else
        {
            $add         = "INSERT INTO table (timeout,timein)
                                   VALUES ('$time_out_user','$time_in_user')";
            $addDateTime = mysqli_query($connect,$add);
            echo "Time added";
        }
    }
?>
<form action="time.php" method="post">  
    <table> 
        <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> </td>
            <td>Time Out: </td>
            <td><input type ="time" name="timeout" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> </td>
            <td>Time In: </td>
            <td><input type ="time" name="timein" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>    

    <p><input class="btnSuccess" type ="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> </p>              
</form>
```

Appreciate if someone can help me to solve this problem . Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work with timestamt 
use `strtotime` to convert date to time stamp:

```
$timeout        = strtotime('08:30:00');
$timein         = strtotime('12:30:00');
$time_out_user  = strtotime($_POST['timeout']);
$time_in_user   = strtotime($_POST['timein']);
```

Comment: it works , thanks . btw . if time using strtotime , what about date ? is it using the same technique .

Comment: the value of time inserted in database is 838:59:59 . i don't know why . but the erros works perfectly